# DataSource error with Springboot

Tags: mysql, maven, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, vaadin

I have an issue when running a spring boot project of mine:

I am using Vaadin for UI and Maven for dependecies. The Database is a MySQL one and I have followed the instructions from (https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/) closely.

> Description:
>
> Parameter 0 of constructor in
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration
>   required a bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' that could not be
>   found.
>     - Bean method 'dataSource' not loaded because @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.datasource.jndi-name) did not find property 'jndi-name'
>     - Bean method 'dataSource' not loaded because @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.boot.jta.XADataSourceWrapper;
>   SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans
>
> Action:
>
> Consider revisiting the conditions above or defining a bean of type
>   'javax.sql.DataSource' in your configuration.

**With --debug:**
Full auto-configuration report (too long for this post)

https://pastebin.com/DEsAkpLi

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ethereum</groupId>
    <artifactId>TradeSafe</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>TradeSafe</name>
    <description>TradeSafe WebService</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.web3j</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.web3j</groupId>
            <artifactId>web3j-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>8.0.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>org.jboss.repository.releases</id>
            <name>JBoss Maven Release Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

**TradeLayout.java**

```
package ethereum.tradesafe;

import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import com.vaadin.spring.annotation.SpringComponent;
import com.vaadin.ui.GridLayout;


@SpringComponent
public class TradeLayout extends GridLayout{
    @Autowired
    private TradeRepo repo;

    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
        update();
    }

    private void setTrades(List<Trade> trades) {
        removeAllComponents();

        trades.forEach(trade-> addComponent(new TradeItemLayout(trade)));

    }

    public Object add(Trade trade) {
        repo.save(trade);
        update();
        return null;
    }

    private void update() {
        setTrades((List<Trade>) repo.findAll());

    }

}
```

**TradeRepo.java**

```
package ethereum.tradesafe;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface TradeRepo extends CrudRepository<Trade, Long>{

}
```

application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://nottheproblem/db_tradesafe
spring.datasource.username=nottheproblem
spring.datasource.password=nottheproblem
```

Comment: Can you share a complete sample application on GitHub that shows the problem? Also, what does the auto-configuration report show when you start your application with a `--debug` argument?

Comment: How do I make a sample application?

Comment: I added the --debug output

Comment: Did you not get a complete auto-configuration report in your logs?

Comment: I edited with complete report: my console output was limited

Comment: This line of the report `DataSourceAutoConfiguration.PooledDataSourceCondition.ExplicitType @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.datasource.type) did not find property 'type' (DataSourceAutoConfiguration.PooledDataSourceCondition)` suggests that `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource` cannot be found. Your POM file looks correct to me, so I think the only way you're going to get help is to share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Try to add @Repository annotation above the TradeRepo, and also rename it to TradeRepository

Answer (score 0):

Solved this error by adding (missing in my case) maven dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```